# a really strange bug when my python program working with mysqll

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

here is the code

```
sql="SELECT node_id FROM %s WHERE domain='%s';"%(config.nodetable,url)
r=getBySql(sql)
```

my problem is trying to save data in mysql db so this code should was executed repeatedly for like more than hundred thousands of times. and at the beginning everything went well, until several times the interpretor return the error:

```
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 35, 
in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'h' in 'where clause'")
```

but I find the sql string to be executed is totally OK as:

```
SELECT node_id FROM testnodewww WHERE domain='http://service.qq.com';
```

I totally have no idea about it. why it was working good at first? and why the error informed of "unknown column 'h'"?? my code have nothing to do with column h at all...

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

MySQLdb will convert your parameter into a SQL literal, do not use single quotes in your sql string, or a semi-colon at the end, and don't use string interpolation:

```
sql = "SELECT node_id FROM %s WHERE domain=%s" % (config.nodetable, url)
```

Do this instead:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT node_id FROM %s WHERE domain=%s", (config.nodetable, url))
```

Comment: no,the execute function will automatically add quates at config.nodetable which will cause a syntax error

Comment: Then change your execute function, do not try to escape things yourself, you will screw it up. That's almost certainly your problem here.

Comment: thankyou and may I ask what cause this problem and why the error message include a column 'h' coming from no where?

Comment: No way to know for sure without seeing all of your code, it was probably due to how you were trying to create the SQL literals by hand